# How to combine two rows into a single column value in R

Tags: r, statistics

How to combine two rows into a single column value in R

Original Output

[image: Original Output]

Expected Output

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Where would you like to do this - a table in a document, _e.g._ PDF or HTML? That's the only context in which it makes sense as it is a formatting issue, nothing to do with how R stores data in _e.g._ a data frame.

Comment: I wanted to do in the table and below is the R-code which I'm using for the formatting table.





final_table %>%
  kbl(caption = "Name of the table") %>%
  kable_styling()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `kableExtra::collapse_rows` will do it. Something like this:

```
final_table %>% 
  kbl(caption = "Name of the table") %>% 
  collapse_rows(column = 1)
```